# How to upgrade versions of postgresql without losing statistics

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm upgrading from 9.5 to 9.6. Running vacuum analyze on the whole db to regenerate stats is a pain. Is there any way to upgrade and migrate over the statistics so I dont have to regenerate them?

Comment: Not AFAIK. `pg_upgrade` won't move them, and backup and restore won't either. This [post](http://blog.endpoint.com/2016/12/postgres-statistics-and-pain-of-analyze.html) seems to agree with this fact. It will also suggest alternatives to ANALYZE faster.